# Linux GUI how to delete from cursor to end of line

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I know on the command line, ctrl + k will delete from cursor to the end of line. Ctrl + k also works on mac GUI programs like chrome, finder text input boxes.

But in linux, in firefox or gnome file explorer text inputs, ctrl + k does not work. Is there another keyboard shortcut for this?

I believe the linux distribution I am currently using is based on CentOS, if this question is distro dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Windows and Linux apps (actually the GUI widgets, so its not program-specific)) have standardized on

- `shift-End` to select from cursor to end of line (`shift-Home` selects in the other direction)
- followed by `Delete` to delete the selection

Comment: good alternative

Answer (score -1):

In my experience ctrl+k is completely valid (and behaves as expected) within *terminal emulators*, at least those running BASH (ZSH and others may have specifically different or user-defined functionality).  For other text fields the only similar shortcut I'm aware of is ctrl+u, which will delete the entire line regardless of cursor position.

I suspect this sort of behavior is extremely program-specific, though, unless a desktop environment or window manager will facilitate it.  I may be wrong in which case I hope someone comes and corrects me.